# LINQ aggregate multiple tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following database. A list of companies. Each company has multiple employees and multiple contractors.

```
dbo.Companies (CompanyId, Name)
dbo.Employees (Id, CompanyId, Name ...)
dbo.Contractors(Id, CompanyId, Name...)
```

I want to get output like so

```
CompanyName #Employees #Contractors
abc           0             10
xyz           25            999
```

I am trying to avoid doing 2 queries, one to get contractors and one to get employees and then merging them. Is there a way to get it done in one go?

n.b. i have

```
class CompanySummary{
string Name {get; set;}
int EmpCount {get; set;}
int ConCount {get; set;}
}
```

so I can use a collection of this type as result

Comment: Why you are not using join for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have defined **navigation properties** (and if you haven't, may be it's a good time to do that), the query should be quite simple:

```
var query = from c in db.Companies
            select new CompanySummary
            {
                Name = c.Name,
                EmpCount = c.Employees.Count(),
                ConCount = c.Contractors.Count(),
            };
```

Of course you can do that manually, but the above is the preferred way with EF:

```
var query = from c in db.Companies
            select new CompanySummary
            {
                Name = c.Name,
                EmpCount = db.Employees.Count(e => e.CompanyId == c.Id),
                ConCount = db.Contractors.Count(cc => cc.CompanyId == c.Id),
            };
```

In both cases you'll get a single SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework to communicate with the database and have the tables linked with foreign keys you can probably do it in one query. It would look something like this:

```
IEnumerable<CompanySummary> companySummary = null; 

using (CompanyEntities dbContext = new CompanyEntities())
{
     companySummary = dbContext.Companies
         .Include(company => company.Employees)
         .Include(company => company.Contractors)
         .Select(company => new CompanySummary
         {
             Name = company.Name,
             EmpCount = company.Employees.Count(),
             ConCount = company.Contractors.Count()
         });
}
```